# update by accessing record only once.

Tags: sql, oracle

sql update depending on the current value. a table(id,color,code) value for code are (a,b,c,...) How can i change all a to AA and c to CC without accessing a record more than once.

I think its like getting code for each color and if a -> AA and if c -> CC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Case statement`

```
update yourtable
set code = case code when 'a' then 'AA' 
                     when 'c' then 'CC'
           END
Where code in('a','c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an amusing alternative:

```
update t
    set code = upper(code) || upper(code)
    where code in ('a', 'c');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access each record only once you can use two separate updates:

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE
  SET CODE = 'AA'
  WHERE CODE = 'a'
```

and

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE
  SET CODE = 'CC'
  WHERE CODE = 'c'
```

This only accesses the records to be updated once.

Best of luck.

Comment: If these updates result in full table scans, each row will be accessed, read, many times.

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional choice, you can also do it this way:

```
 UPDATE TABLE SET CODE = RPAD(CODE,LENGTH(CODE)*2,UPPER(CODE)) WHERE CODE IN ('a','b')
```

This will update the code twice it's current value so this is also ideal for updating codes with varying lengths(eg. ab will become ABAB, abb to ABBABB)